# WHy a constant char breaks Loop and Switch statements

Tags: c++, char, switch-statement, constants

I am making a simple currency conversion program using a switch statement as shown below:

```
#include "library/std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{//This program converts yen, euros, yuan, kroner and pounds to dollars
double amount = 0; 
char currency = ' ';

//one dollar equivalent of each currency
const double yen_to_dollar = 113.67;
const double pounds_to_dollar = 0.85; 
const double euros_to_dollar = 0.95;
const double yuan_to_dollar = 6.87;
const double kroner_to_dollar = 7.04; 

//case labels corresponding to currency
const char y = 'y', p = 'p', e = 'e', u = 'u', k = 'k';

cout << "Please type the amount you want to convert, followed by the currency(y,e,p,u,k) u is for yuan: "; 

while(cin >> amount >> currency ) {
    switch(currency) {
        case y:
            cout << amount << " yen == " << amount / yen_to_dollar << " dollars." << '\n';
            break; 

        case p: 
            cout << amount << " pounds == " << amount / pounds_to_dollar << " dollars." <<'\n';
            break; 

        case e: 
            cout << amount << " euros == " << amount / euros_to_dollar << " dollars." << '\n';
            break; 

        case u: 
            cout << amount << " yuan == " << amount / yuan_to_dollar << " dollars." << '\n';
            break; 

        case k: 
            cout << amount << " kroner == " << amount / kroner_to_dollar << " dollars." << '\n';
            break; 

        default: 
            cout << "Please try supported currencies" << '\n';
            break;  
    }   
}

  return 0;
}
```

I can convert the predefined currencies to dollars when the function is run by inputting amount and currency, like this: 5y (converts 5 yen to the dollar equivalent). 
Every other amount and constant work EXCEPT the `e` constant. The code ends anytime I want to test it with an amount and constant e.g. (24e).

When I change the constant `e = 'e'` to something like `s = 's'`, it works very well.

So my question is why would the input containing an e character break my code?

Comment: there is no `case: e`

Comment: that code wont compile, as you still have `case: s` but not `s` defined, only `e`. Please make sure the code you show reproduces the behaviour you describe.

Comment: That was an error. I tested it with case s and it worked. I forgot to revert back to case e when i asked this question. have edited to case e now. And it still breaks the loop and switch statements

Comment: I think that was the problem. `24y` or `24 y` works. BUT `1e` will not work but `1 e` works. It seems the compiler interprets `1e` different from the way it interprets `1y`?

Comment: @OnomeSotu `1e` is a parsed as an number, because `e` is an exponent. For `1y`, only `1` is parsed as a number, and `y` as `char`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. @Rakete1111 It is much clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might NOT be it but is the entered "23.4e" value being interpreted as an exponent?  That would be my thought here.  You might consider parsing it removing the string/char part first into your variable for that part.

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem. I think the compiler reads `1e` as an exponent as opposed to how it reads `1y`. When I test with `1 e` it outputs the right result. Can I ask why it accepts both `1y` and `1 y` inputs even though the former has no white space?

Comment: Each formatted input operation skip any leading whitespace.

Comment: Numbers CAN have an `e` character as in `1.535625e+009` or such, it indicates an exponent and can thus make a "number" from a string containing one.  Look at parsing and c++ to understand this - there is lots of info on tht.